# Visualize the edge thickness in tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I want the graph visualizer to label edges with tensor dimensions, and edge thickness to reflect total tensor size. Basically exactly the same as written in [this doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graph_viz#tensor_shape_information):

> When the serialized GraphDef includes tensor shapes, the graph
>   visualizer labels edges with tensor dimensions, and edge thickness
>   reflects total tensor size. To include tensor shapes in the GraphDef
>   pass the actual graph object (as in sess.graph) to the FileWriter when
>   serializing the graph. The images below show the CIFAR-10 model with
>   tensor shape information:

[image]

I pass the graph object to my summary.FileWriter:

`writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(_dir_tensorboard, graph=sess.graph, flush_secs=300)`

But I do not get any information about the *thickness* (all the lines are of the same size). I have just information about the shape of a tensor and information about the number of tensors.

How can I achive the same visual effect as the tutorial claims?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a regression impacting 1.11 and 1.12. It should be fixed with https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/pull/1544. Sorry about it :( Please file a GitHub issue next time this happens.